# Get value of attribute in Angularjs custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am gonna get the count of letters in the textbox and show it in div tag which is featured by element directive .

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  <div counter-directive max-length="100" ng-model="name"></div>
```

div tag has to show something like this :    12/100  (12 is what we typed in input and 100 is the value of max-length )

the problem is , I don't know how to get the value of max-length .

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/peyman_gilmour/09nw12kc/6/) i have the example on jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firsly, check your spelling. You've used `lenght` a couple times in your question.

You can get the `max-length` attribute from the `attrs` object passed into the `link` function.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var foo = attrs.maxLength;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to do this:

```
app.directive('counterDirective', function () {

return {

    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: { maxLength:'=', ngModel:'&' },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log(scope.maxLength);

        scope.$watch(scope.ngModel, function (value) {

            if (value) {

                var newValue = value.length;
                console.log(value);
                element[0].innerText = newValue;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

});

I think you have to replace 'lenght' by 'length' :)

Comment: Thanks for answer . but why scope.$watch does not work anymore when ngModel get change ?

Comment: It works for me, here is a plunker which display the new value in your directive each time you change your ngModel. https://jsfiddle.net/09nw12kc/7/

Comment: Sorry I didnt understood your question. I updated the plunker and now it works properly :) https://jsfiddle.net/09nw12kc/9/

Comment: yes it works . but as u told me above , i need use scope:{ maxLength:'=' }  and get the value of attribute like  scope.maxLength  .  in your jsfiddle i can see just my first example as i gave u without scope:{ maxLength:'=' }   and ....

Comment: Thank u so much :)